# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - boxNode.addChildNode(importedBox!)

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have some code that runs a for loop to create 2 objects and stuffs them into the boxArray then adds them to the scene. The first time through the code works fine to create one box but during the addBox(num: Int) function to create the second box it crashes with the error in the subject line. Its this line that is responsible "boxNode.addChildNode(importedBox!)" but Im at a loss as to why since it works the first time.

```
    importedSceneBox = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/boxObject.dae")

    for var i = 0; i <= 1; ++i {

        let boxNode = self.addBox(i)
        boxArray.append(boxNode)
        theScene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxArray[i])
    }

func addBox(num: Int) -> SCNNode{

    let boxNode = SCNNode()
    let importedBox = importedSceneBox.rootNode.childNodeWithName("pCube4", recursively: false)
    importedBox?.scale = SCNVector3Make(70, 70, 70)
    boxNode.addChildNode(importedBox!)
    boxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(5, 100, 3)
    let collisionBox = SCNBox(width: 5.0, height: 5.0, length: 5.0, chamferRadius: 0)
    boxNode.physicsBody?.physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: collisionBox, options: nil)
    boxNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()
    boxNode.physicsBody?.mass = 1
    boxNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.8
    boxNode.physicsBody?.damping = 0.5
    boxNode.name = "dice" + String(num)
    boxNode.physicsBody?.allowsResting = true

    return boxNode
}
```

Comment: can you upload a sample proj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi your importedBox is an optional meaning it can have a value or it can be nil.
you are using "!"(IUO implicitly unwrapped optional) behind importedBox which means that your telling the compiler that your sure its not be nil. How ever in this case it WAS nil thus the crash "found nil when unwrapping optional"

So recap importedBox is nil but you marked it with ! so the compiler think it will never have a nil value but a nil was found thus the crash.

to fix this you can use guard or optional binding 
Guard example

```
func addBox(num: Int) -> SCNNode{

    let boxNode = SCNNode()
    let importedBox = importedSceneBox.rootNode.childNodeWithName("pCube4", recursively: false)
    importedBox?.scale = SCNVector3Make(70, 70, 70)
    guard let unwrapBox = importedBox else { 
     //do your error handling here 
       return SCNNode()
    }
    boxNode.addChildNode(unwrapBox)
    boxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(5, 100, 3)
    let collisionBox = SCNBox(width: 5.0, height: 5.0, length: 5.0, chamferRadius: 0)
    boxNode.physicsBody?.physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: collisionBox, options: nil)
    boxNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()
    boxNode.physicsBody?.mass = 1
    boxNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.8
    boxNode.physicsBody?.damping = 0.5
    boxNode.name = "dice" + String(num)
    boxNode.physicsBody?.allowsResting = true

    return boxNode
}
```

optional binding example

```
func addBox(num: Int) -> SCNNode{

    let boxNode = SCNNode()
    let importedBox = importedSceneBox.rootNode.childNodeWithName("pCube4", recursively: false)
    importedBox?.scale = SCNVector3Make(70, 70, 70)
    if  let unwrapBox = importedBox else { 
        boxNode.addChildNode(unwrapBox)
        boxNode.position = SCNVector3Make(5, 100, 3)
        let collisionBox = SCNBox(width: 5.0, height: 5.0, length: 5.0,     chamferRadius: 0)
        boxNode.physicsBody?.physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: collisionBox, options: nil)
        boxNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()
        boxNode.physicsBody?.mass = 1
        boxNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.8
        boxNode.physicsBody?.damping = 0.5
        boxNode.name = "dice" + String(num)
        boxNode.physicsBody?.allowsResting = true

        return boxNode
    }else{
        //do your error handling here 
       return SCNNode()
    }
}
```

also as a side note in the error handling cases we are creating a default value since your function returns a SCNNode and not a SCNNode optional.
Alternatively you can return nil if you change your function signature to be

```
func addBox(num: Int) -> SCNNode? {
     if let unwrappedBox = importedBox {
       //do stuff
     }else{
        return nil 
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, those are some good answers - I need to learn more about this topic. Would you have any idea as to why it is returning nil? The reason being is that the for loop produces one box but on the second iteration I am getting nil. Or is it that I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: @JeremyRaven the function your calling importedSceneBox.rootNode.childNodeWithName("pCube4", recursively: false) returns an optional which means it can be nil depending on if its dependencies are met. Looks like the second call to childNodeWithName did not find "pCube4" per the documentation it traverses pre order through the children to find the child named pCube4 which it did not find link here https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNNode/childNodeWithName:recursively: did that child get deleted ?

Comment: try setting recursively: to true just realized it was false